# I can't use git in the ubuntu terminal without entering credentials every time I want to interact with the remote repository

Tags: git

I work with Visual Studio Code, and from there I work with git without problems, but when I try to work from the ubuntu terminal either it asks me for username and password (Personal access token), I can't configure it to not ask me every time for the credentials but there is no way.

I have a generated ssh key, the data in the .gitconfig file are correct, I have also tried adding the public key fingerprints, using the command:

```
$ ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

did not work, I tried adding in the global configuration the token as user.password, also did not work, another attempt was to cache it with the commands:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:*******/*******.git
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:helenamnx/helloGit.git
$ git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=10800'
```

And neither, the funny thing is that from Visual I have no problem.
I would appreciate your help, thanks and greetings from Canarias !!!!!

Comment: Have you configured ssh to use your ssh key when connecting to github.com (in `~/.ssh/config`)?

Comment: Are you trying to use a Personal Access Token or an ssh key?  They're completely different.  For an ssh key, you need to add the public key to your github account (in the settings under ssh keys)

Comment: @HelenaRodríguez, greetings from the central united states.   Like many folks here, I am sadly not multilingual.   Please use English on this site; alternately, there is a spanish site https://es.stackoverflow.com/.